# Pandas fillna multiple columns with values from corresponding columns without repeating for each

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fillna

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'col1_x': [15, np.nan, 136, 93, 743, np.nan, np.nan, 91] ,                                        
                  'col2_x': [np.nan, np.nan, 51, 22, 38, np.nan, 72, np.nan], 
                  'col1_y': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
                  'col2_y': [93, 24, 52, 246, 142, 53, 94, 2]})
```

And I want to fill the `NaN` values in `col_x` with the values in `col_y` respectively,
I can do this:

```
x['col1_x'] = x['col1_x'].fillna(x['col1_y'])
x['col2_x'] = x['col2_x'].fillna(x['col2_y'])

print(x)
```

Which will yield:

```
   col1_x  col2_x  col1_y  col2_y
0    15.0    93.0      10      93
1    20.0    24.0      20      24
2   136.0    51.0      30      52
3    93.0    22.0      40     246
4   743.0    38.0      50     142
5    60.0    53.0      60      53
6    70.0    72.0      70      94
7    91.0     2.0      80       2
```

**But** requires to repeat the same function with different variables, now let's assume that I have a bigger DataFrame with much more columns, is it possible to do it without repeating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use ****kwargs** to `assign()`
- build up a **dict** with a comprehension to build ****kwargs**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame({'col1_x': [15, np.nan, 136, 93, 743, np.nan, np.nan, 91] ,                                        
                  'col2_x': [np.nan, np.nan, 51, 22, 38, np.nan, 72, np.nan], 
                  'col1_y': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
                  'col2_y': [93, 24, 52, 246, 142, 53, 94, 2]})

x.assign(**{c:x[c].fillna(x[c.replace("_x","_y")]) for c in x.columns if "_x" in c})
```

|  | col1_x | col2_x | col1_y | col2_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 93 | 10 | 93 |
| 1 | 20 | 24 | 20 | 24 |
| 2 | 136 | 51 | 30 | 52 |
| 3 | 93 | 22 | 40 | 246 |
| 4 | 743 | 38 | 50 | 142 |
| 5 | 60 | 53 | 60 | 53 |
| 6 | 70 | 72 | 70 | 94 |
| 7 | 91 | 2 | 80 | 2 |

#### How does it work

```
# core - loop through columns that end with _x and generate it's pair column _y
{c:c.replace("_x","_y") 
 for c in x.columns if "_x" in c}

# now we have all the pairs of a columns let's do what we want - fillna()
{c:x[c].fillna(x[c.replace("_x","_y")]) for c in x.columns if "_x" in c}

# this dictionary matches this function.... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html
# so final part is call the function with **kwargs
x.assign(**{c:x[c].fillna(x[c.replace("_x","_y")]) 
            for c in x.columns if "_x" in c})
```

Comment: I'm breaking my head right now trying to understand what it all means, some of it I get but most of it I don't. Colud you please briefly explain what it does?

Comment: I have added a "how does it work" section to answer.  there is lot's of information on python **kwargs .... maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following notation -

```
x.fillna({"col1_x": x["col1_y"], "col2_x": x["col2_y"]})
```

Assuming you can extract all the indices numbers you can do -

```
replace_dict = {f"col{item}_x":x[f"col{item}_y"] for item in indices}
x = x.fillna(replace_dict}
```

Comment: ``x.fillna({"col1_x": x["col1_y"], "col2_x": x["col2_y"]})`` Honestly that's exactly what I was looking for but I guess I did it wrong,  Thanks for the input! I'd accept this as an answer too if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make this type of function :

```
def fil(fill,fromm):
    fill.fillna(fromm,inplace=True)

fil(x['col1_x'],x['col1_y'])
```

Or if you are sure about dataframe(x) then this :

```
def fil(fill,fromm):
    x[fill].fillna(x[fromm],inplace=True)

fil('col1_x','col1_y')
```

For your code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame({'col1_x': [15, np.nan, 136, 93, 743, np.nan, np.nan, 91] ,                                
                  'col2_x': [np.nan, np.nan, 51, 22, 38, np.nan, 72, np.nan], 
                  'col1_y': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
                  'col2_y': [93, 24, 52, 246, 142, 53, 94, 2]})


def fil(fill,fromm):
    x[fill].fillna(x[fromm],inplace=True)

fil('col1_x','col1_y')
fil('col2_x','col2_y')

print(x)

"""
   col1_x  col2_x  col1_y  col2_y
0    15.0    93.0      10      93
1    20.0    24.0      20      24
2   136.0    51.0      30      52
3    93.0    22.0      40     246
4   743.0    38.0      50     142
5    60.0    53.0      60      53
6    70.0    72.0      70      94
7    91.0     2.0      80       2
"""
```

Additionally, if you have column name like col1_x,col2_x,col3_x.... same for y then you may automate it like this :

```
for i in range(1,3):
    fil(f'col{i}_x',f'col{i}_y')
```

Comment: Thanks! that's certainly a one way to do it, can't believe I didn't think of it tho

Comment: @TomerPoliakov This is like a universal solution, cuz accepted answer, only works when column name is specific but my answer works for all name of column. Anyway for you that works. :)

Comment: actually quite the opposite, with your solution I have to specify the names of every column and since I have quite a bunch of them, it will look ugly, while with the answer I have accepted I only have to specify the ending which is the default ending of ``merge`` module. tho, I can't not agree that your solution is much easier to understand compared to the whatever it is I accepted. I appreciate your Input! Thanks!